# Trouble with simple google script send email with cc

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

Please someone help me with this code.I need to add cc with different emails in 1 column.

Hope someone can help me.

```
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 20; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:C3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        var message = row[1]; // Second column
        var subject = "EXCEPTION REPORT";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the options parameter of `.sendEmail` as in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options).

```
 function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 20; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:C3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        var ccAddress = row[--index of cc column--];
        var message = row[1]; // Second column
        var subject = "EXCEPTION REPORT";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {cc : ccAddress});
    }
}
```